# calculate multiple columns mean in R and generate a new table

Tags: r

I have a data set in .csv. It contains multiple columns for example.

```
Group Wk1 WK2 WK3 WK4 WK5 WK6 
   A   1   2   3   4   5   6
   B   7   8   9   1   2   3
   C   4   5   6   7   8   9
   D   1   2   3   4   5   6
```

Then if I want to have the mean of both WK1 & WK2, Wk3, WK4 & WK5, WK6.
How can I do that?
The result may like

```
Group 1    2    3    4
mean  3.75 5.25 4.5  6
```

And how can I save it into a new table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @eddi, they want to group some columns but not others, so `colMeans` isn't the direct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can `melt` your `data.frame`, create your groups using some basic indexing, and use `aggregate`:

```
library(reshape2)
X <- melt(mydf, id.vars="Group")
Match <- c(Wk1 = 1, Wk2 = 1, Wk3 = 2, Wk4 = 3, Wk5 = 3, Wk6 = 4)
aggregate(value ~ Match[X$variable], X, mean)
#   Match[X$variable] value
# 1                 1  3.75
# 2                 2  5.25
# 3                 3  4.50
# 4                 4  6.00
```

---

`tapply` is also an appropriate candidate here:

```
tapply(X$value, Match[X$variable], mean)
#    1    2    3    4 
# 3.75 5.25 4.50 6.00
```

Comment: Hi @Ananda Mahto, your function works pretty well in the situation above. However, if the columns contain many variables, let's say about 200, and I want to pair them like above, then what should be the best way to do it?

Comment: @ShunzheYao, is there any pattern to the pairings? If yes, use that to create your column groups.